# IF statements influencing the input variable?

Tags: sas

[image]

Hello.

I am not sure why the code does not result in reading 11.

can some one explain that to me?

Comment: After employee_name is read the next input statement starts on a new line.  You need @ at end of first input statement to hold the line.

Comment: Thank you.  That is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data step will run two INPUT statements on each iteration.  Because there is no trailing `@`  on the first one it will read two lines each time.

So first it reads columns 1-4 of one line. Then based on the condition being tested it either reads from columns 7-8 or 10-11 of the second line.